# NGINX gives strange response output for ngx.capture.location method call

Tags: php, nginx, lua

I'm using NGINX to call another apache/PHP service. Following is my NGINX code,

```
 location /hello {

    content_by_lua_block {
        res = ngx.location.capture("/forward2");
        ngx.say("status: " .. res.status);
        ngx.say("result: " .. res.body);
    }
}

location /forward2{

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2002/index2.php;
}
```

I have a very simple php code,

```
<?php 

    echo "123456789";
    echo "123456789";
    echo "123456789";
    echo "123456789";
    echo "123456789";
    echo "123456789";
```

My problem is whever I exceed the number of output characters in php sctpt more than 65 characters I get following strange output for body

```
   status: 200 result: ‹30426153·°4Ò,@£)AÈ
```

If i have less output characters in PHP code then I get correct output as following, (in following case only three php echo lines)

```
status: 200 result: 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

Do you have any idea about why this is happennning?

Note: If i access to php directly (Not via NGINX), I always get correct output for any number of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled many days with this problem. But at last I found a solution by myself. The problem here is very simple and its related to PHP/apache.

If there are more than 60 characters then Apache will use gzip encoding automatically. So I can't just echo that output from the nginx server. There must be a way to handle this in NGINX server. But for now I just disabled gzip encoding from PHP using following code line.

```
apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
```